# REST - get custom user profile property - on premise - Infopath

Tags: 2013, infopath, rest

I want to retrieve a custom field from the user profile property with rest. The property is searchable in search. Name of the custom properties "CompanyNumber"

But when I try to use 
http://companyname.com/site/sitename/_api/SP.UserProfiles:peopleManager/GetMyProperties

it does not retieve the custom properties, only the built in properties like :

- AccountName
- DirectReports
- DisplayName
- Email
- ....

I get a node that says UserProfileProperties where there is a Key? But how do I use this?

**INFOPATH**

I have to use infopath so pure javascript does not work :(

What I realy want to do is to type in the CompanyNumber and then the adress / postnumber / etc. get autopopulated

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var theData = {
 "propertiesForUser": {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser" }, 
    "accountName": "domain\username",
    "propertyNames": ["CompanyNumber"]
     }
};

var requestHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
};

jQuery.ajax({
    url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertiesFor",
    type:"POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(theData),
    contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){
        console.log(jqxr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Source : http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Comment: TY for the answer, but I've already been on the url. But this is Infopath :(

Comment: Ok, have you tried `Select CompanyNumber` in the URL?

Comment: No, can you please give me an url example?

Comment: http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=CompanyNumber

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. It worked for me for getting current user custom property details. Make sure the **CompanyNumber** is internal name of your field in User Profile Service.

```
//Display User profile properties
function getMyUserProfile(success, error) {
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl; //You can replace this with your site URL too. i.e http://anysite.com
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.d));
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.UserProfileProperties.results.length; i++) {
                if (data.d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Key == "CompanyNumber") {
                    alert("Your Custom Property Company Number is : " + data.d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Value);
                }
            }
        },
        error: error
    });
}

// Usage   
getMyUserProfile(function (properties) {},
      function (data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
```

Try below URL for more details.

http://fixingsharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-get-custom-user-profile-property.html